# CRM 2011 Sub-grid for Price List Matrix

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am trying to add feature to Price List entity to support matrix based price lists.
I had created Price List Columns and Price List Rows entity and added 1-N relations to Price List entity.

Now i have to add a subgrid in a Price List form (probably a new one) to let users fill matrix. So i need a grid that fetches and inserts columns from Price List Columns relation and  fetches and inserts rows from Price List Rows relation.

Is this possible? If yes, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are asking, 'How can I build an editable sub grid?'

Well out of the box CRM doesnt support those features. You will have to build (or buy) something custom.

I would suggest having a read of [Building an editable grid for CRM 2011](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devkeydet/archive/2011/11/30/building-an-editable-grid-for-crm-2011.aspx) which offers a number of existing addons and suggest development approaches.

Comment: yes, the right question may be this. i am checking the article. thanx, if it helps me i will accept your answer.